# Não paginar a listagem de Produtos

Tags: c#, webforms, razor, razor-pages

Eu não conheço nada de Razor ou Webmatrix. Eu peguei um projeto já feito por outro desenvolvedor e me deparei com dois problemas, não consigo localizar onde ficão as consultas SQL para listar os produtos e também não sei como fazer para que quando listar os Produtos, não aparecer a paginação, isto é listar diretamente, todos os produtos do banco de dados sem paginar.
Será que vocês podem me ajudar? Segue parte do código.

```
@model IEnumerable<MZANovoMVC4.Models.Produto>

@model PagedList.IPagedList<MZANovoMVC4.Models.Produto>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Produtos - ";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_Interno.cshtml";
}






<div class="container">
    <main id="content" class="col-md-12 main-blog" tabindex="-1" role="main" asd="1">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:50px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;">

            <div class="col-md-4 filter">
                <div class="filtro-produto">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="~/produtos">TODOS</a></li>
                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Categorias)
                        {
                            <li>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Produto", new { idcategoria = item.IDCategoria, categoria = item.TituloTratado })">
                                    @item.Titulo
                                    <img class="sidebar-img" src="@item.Foto">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        }

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <main id="content" class="col-md-8 main-produto" tabindex="-1" role="main" asd="1">
                <div class="category-name">Linha Completa</div>
                <div class="produtos-topo" id="response">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <article class="box-produto post">
                        <img src="@item.Foto" width="800" height="450" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" 
                             alt="" sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px" data-lazy-loaded="true" style="display: block;">
                        <h3>@item.Titulo</h3>
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(@item.Medidas))
                        {
                            <h4> Medidas:@item.Medidas</h4>
                        }                        
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Produto", new { id = item.IDProduto, name = item.TituloTratado})">Ver Produto</a>
                    </article>
                }


                </div>
                <div style="text-align:center;">
                    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, p => Url.Action("Index", new { p, b = ViewBag.Busca }))
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Fábio esse projeto parece ser um projeto em MVC nesse caso você deve ter um Controller que é aonde fica a lógica e é de lá que vem os os dados.

Answer (score 0):

> não consigo localizar onde ficão as consultas SQL para listar os
>   produtos

Essa lista é abastecida no `controller` da página, basta procurar sua `ActionResult`.

Dependendo de como foi estruturado o projeto, pode estar vindo de uma `Model` e/ou na própria `Model` tem um chamada para uma classe `DAO` que faz toda parte `CRUD` de uma aplicação. E ainda pode existe a possibilidade de ter mais uma classe de negócio que seria a `.BLL`.

Sugiro você estudar um pouco sobre camadas [MVC](http://www.macoratti.net/vbn_mvc.htm) e sobre a classe .[BLL](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/introduction/creating-a-business-logic-layer-cs).

Mas olhando seu o código, procure a `Model` `Produto` dentro do source do projeto, é de lá que está vindo essa **Lista**, bem como a chamada no banco.

Sobre a questão da paginação precisa checar senão está sendo utilizado algum [plugin](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html)

Comment: Pelo que vi, tem este plugin no arquivo packages.config <package id="PagedList" version="1.17.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="PagedList.Mvc" version="4.5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />